# How can I create a system to process files directly after they are transferred to a different server?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, queue

Currently, I have a server that needs to batch process a bunch of files. All of the files are on Server A, which is running Ubuntu, but I need them to be processed on a macos server. Right now, I have a script that will transfer all the files from Server A to Server B, process all the files, then transfer all the files back to Server A.

The bash file looks like this (simplified):

```
script -q -c "scp -r files_to_process b:process_these 2>&1"
ssh b "process_all.sh"
script -q -c "scp -r processed_files a:final_dir 2>&1"
```

My question is this: is there any easy way to implement a simple queue between these servers?
Once a file has been transferred to b, I am wasting time by not just processing the files immediately.